# Flurry Analytics "Table Failed to Load" Error

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, flurry

I've literally just released my first iOS app (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quiet-classroom/id825582891?ls=1&mt=8), and I'm using Flurry Analytics on it. All through the development stage this has worked perfectly well, but now when I try to see what's going on with my app I see the following:

[image: Table Not Loading]

Before launching it showed up fine and listed my app, which I could click on and view all my sessions/custom events. Has this happened to anyone else? Is this a good thing - does it mean lots of people are using my app, or is it a bad thing - Have I managed to mess up the analytics code?

Comment: I think I know the problem... You're using Flurry!

Comment: And now it's down for maintenance 10 minutes after my app goes live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this problem. It just means the `Flurry Analytics` is having problems. There is nothing you can do. You have to wait and try again in some time.